# Can we test downloading of files in CircleCI

Tags: cypress, circleci

I have a test that downloads excel files from a site and the test also requires to check the sheetnames of the excel file. I already got passed on everything in my local but in CircleCI it's returning as 'File not found' (I used this as an error message if file is missing). It cannot locate the file. Is it possible to this in CircleCI?
[image: Local run]

[image]

Here is the code:
test.js

```
cy.get('@transferTestUrl').then((finalLink) => {
    cy.get('@documentPassword').then((password) => {
        const linkBody = { username: testdata.credentials.adminAccountInternalTest,
                           password: password,
                           transferTestLink: finalLink,
                           }
cy.origin('transfer-develop.test.net',{ args: linkBody }, ({ username, password,transferTestLink })=>{
    cy.visit(transferTestLink,{
        auth:{
            username: username,
            password: password
            }
        })

    // to prevent Cypress from loading indefinitely when downloading, only works in Chrome
cy.window().document().then(function (doc) {
    doc.addEventListener('click', () => {
    setTimeout(function () { doc.location.reload() }, 5000)
    })
    cy.get('#downloadButton').click({force:true})
    cy.wait(4000)
                })
            })
        })
    })
    
cy.get('span').contains('courses').invoke('text').then((title) => {
    cy.wrap(title).as('initialDocumentTitle')
    cy.get('@initialDocumentTitle').then((initialTitle) => {
        var convertedTitle = initialTitle.replaceAll(':', "_")
        cy.wrap(convertedTitle).as('downloadedDocumentTitle')
        cy.wait(10000)
        })
    })

cy.get('@courseNameArray').then((courseNamesArray) => {
    cy.log(courseNamesArray)
    cy.get('@downloadedDocumentTitle').then((documentTitle) => {
        //start of reading files from Excel
        var removeSpace = documentTitle.replace(/\s/g, '')
        var excelFilePath = "../CreateAutomatedTests/cypress/downloads/"+removeSpace
        cy.verifyDownload(removeSpace, { interval: 600 })
        cy.wrap(excelFilePath).as('filePath')
    
    cy.get('@filePath').then((filePath) => {
        cy.task('checkExcelSheetContents', { filePath }).then((contents) => {
            cy.log(contents)
            expect(contents).to.deep.equal(courseNamesArray)
            })
        })     
    })
})
```

`plugins/index.js`
[image: plugins index.js]

`commands.js`

```
require('cy-verify-downloads').addCustomCommand();
```

Comment: So cypress is not able to locate the file once it is downloaded? is that right?

Comment: Whats the file path look like?

Comment: @Raju yes, it cannot locate the downloaded file. When I run in my local it works fine

Comment: @jjhelguero filepath is "../CreateAutomatedTests/cypress/downloads/excelsheet.xlsx". I'm able to get a passed result in my local but not in CircleCI

Comment: @FaithBerroya what is the OS on your circleci agent? 

I hope you are searching in the path only after the download is complete. Maybe can you add some code you are using?

Comment: Is this what you meant @Raju? 
version: 2.1
executors:
  macos:
    macos:
      xcode: "11.7.0"
    resource_class: large
  windows:
    machine:
      image: "windows-server-2019-vs2019:stable"
    resource_class: "windows.large"
    shell: "bash.exe"
orbs:
  browser-tools: circleci/browser-tools@1.3.0